# How to use Node.js module in Amazon lambda online console?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm working on a node.js project on the amazon lambda online console.

I didn't find how to include the 'request' module i need.

I tried to add the "request" repository in the zip file i have imported, but i have other errors with "request" sub modules that can't be found ('aws-sign2','aws4','http-signature','mime-types'...)

Answer (score 0):

You must include your `node_modules` folder.

Be sure to execute `npm prune` before the deploy to remove all dev dependencies.

Besides, I recommend you to use serverless to deploy your lambdas.